# Не добавляются данные в базу php

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin, form

Пытаюсь добавить данные в базу. Сам код с формой и самим добавлением:

```
    <?php
session_start();
require_once '../vendor/connect.php';
$url=basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$name=$_POST['element'];
if(isset($_POST['element']))
{
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO `category`(`name`, `parent_id`, `url`) VALUES ('$name','0','$url');");
}
include("header.php");
?>
<div class="container">
<div class="margin">
<h2>Создание списка</h2>
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Имя:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Введите имя элемента" name="element">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Добавить</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

После нажатия на кнопку добавить, в базе не появляются данные которые были введены в Input.

Comment: А вы проверяли наличие данных в `$_POST`? Пропишите также для формы `action="URL"`. И небольшой совет - используйте лучше `PDO` для работы с БД

Comment: Выведите с помощью echo ваш sql запрос ("INSERT INTO `category`(`name`, `parent_id`, `url`) VALUES ('$name','0','$url');") и посмотрите что вы пытаетесь запросить у базы данных. Если и тогда будет не понятно в чем проблема, если у вас phpmyadmin, зайдите и выполните этот ваш sql запрос,  получите текст ошибки от базы данных

Comment: Спасибо, я сперва проверил простой вывод, но особо ничего не понял. Проблема заключалась в том, что у меня не было значений по умолчанию для других полей, которые я не заполнял.